# A question about permutation and cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclic-groups, permutations

Let $S_4$ be the group of permutations on $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and let $G = S_4\oplus \Bbb Z_4$. Find the order of the largest cyclic subgroup of $G$.

Comment: What you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A subgroup of $G=S_4\oplus \Bbb Z_4$ is cyclic if it is generated by just one element. Let $G, H$ be finite groups, and let $g \in G, h \in H$. Then the order of the element $(g,h) \in G \oplus H$ is equal to the least common multiple of the orders of $g$ in $G$ and $h$ in $H$. The elements of $S_4$ have orders $1, 2,3,4$. The elements of $\Bbb Z_4$ have orders $1,2,4$. So we seek to maximize $lcm(a,b)$, where $a \in \{1,2,3,4\}, b \in \{1,2,4\}$. It is easy to see that the maximum value we may obtain is $12=lcm(3,4)$, so by choosing an element $g$ of order $3$ in $S_{4}$, $g=(123)$ for example, and an element $h$ of order $4$ in $\Bbb Z_4$ (e.g. $1 \in \Bbb Z_{4}$ assuming additive notation), the order of $(g,h)=((123),1) \in S_4\oplus \Bbb Z_4$ is $12$. So the order of the largest cyclic subgroup is $12$. $\square$

Comment: how do you calculate the order of $S_4$?

Comment: The order of $S_{4}$ is $4!$ as it's the group of bijections from a 4-element set to itself (with binary operation of function composition)

Comment: If you're unsure as to why the order of $S_{n}$ is $n!$, try to prove it by induction.

Comment: sorry, I wrote it wrong, I mean the order of element of $S_4$, and I have known how to get it. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know that any element of $S_{n}$ may be expressed as a sequence of disjoint cycles of elements of $\{1,...n\}$? The possible cycle types for $S_{4}$ are of the form $1$, $(12)$, $(12)(34)$, $(123)$, $(1234)$. The order of the first type is $1$, for the next two types it's $2$, for the next time it's $3$, and finally $4$ for the last type.